# How do I stop JS query hiding all divs on page when select box option is made?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As shown in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/83y0t0rm/12/

When you select an option from the select box, all divs on the page are removed and only the selected div id from the select box is shown.

Lets say I have multiple divs I want to always remain on the page (content) and only want the filter the show or hide the selected divs in the select box (depending which one is selected)

I'm unclear how the code should be adjusted to achieve this?

I presume, some form of exclude needs adding below?

```
$(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val) {
            $('div:not(#' + val + ')').slideUp();
            $('#' + val).slideDown();
        } 
        else {
            $('div').slideDown();
        }
    });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way you can achieve that is by wrapping the elements with a div element with a specific class: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmvuhmvq/)

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var wrapper = $('.options-wrapper');
    if (val) {
        wrapper.find('div:not(#' + val + ')').slideUp();
        wrapper.find('#' + val).slideDown();
    } 
    else {
        wrapper.find('div').slideDown();
    }
});
```

---

```
<div class="options-wrapper">
    <div id="ActivityBadge" class="containerB" ACTIVITY>badge</div>
    <div id="ActivityFriends" class="containerF" FRIEND 1>friends</div>    
</div>
```

---

The second solution is to add specific class to all divs that you want to slide Up/Down and perform these operations on them. E.g.

```
var divs = $('.divs-to-slide');
....
divs.slideDown();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange way to achieve what you want. Why don't you create a class called "toggle", give it to all relevant elements, and then slideUp like:

```
$(".toggle").slideUp();
```

I think the way you're doing it will be quite slow as opposed to a class selector.